# Insertar datos en otra tabla haciendo uso de un cursor. Sql server

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, cursor

Lo primero agradecer todo tipo de ayuda que me puedan dar.

Mi objetivo es insertar datos de una tabla en otra. Ambas tablas tienen un campo identificativo el cual se genera de forma random mediante el uso de una función. Este campo identificativo en la tabla de destino es único y aquí surge mi problema.

Estoy realizando un cursor con el que voy comparando los campos únicos mencionados anteriormente. Si un registro no existe en la tabla destino se insertará pero en caso de que exista quiero que me actualice el campo identificativo y que lo inserte.

También decir que la función que genera esa clave identificativa esta formada por la fecha actual, la hora, minutos y segundos y 6 dígitos generados aleatoriamente y a pesar de esto, en ocasiones se genera la misma clave.

El código de mi cursor es el siguiente:

```
DECLARE @claves nvarchar(max)

DECLARE lectorClaves CURSOR
    FOR
    SELECT [clave] FROM [dbo].[nombres]

    OPEN lectorClaves

    FETCH NEXT FROM lectorClaves INTO @claves

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        BEGIN       

            IF NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT clave FROM nombres n
                inner join diagnosticos d
                ON n.clave = d.svMaeDia_pky and n.clave = @claves
            )
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO diagnosticos (
                    [svMaeDia_pky],
                    [svMaeDia_diagnostico],
                    [svMaeDia_servicio_fky]
                )
                SELECT 
                    clave, 
                    nombre, 
                    apellido 
                FROM nombres WHERE clave = @claves
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                UPDATE nombres
                SET clave = dbo.NuevaClase() 
                WHERE clave = @claves

                INSERT INTO diagnosticos (
                    [svMaeDia_pky],
                    [svMaeDia_diagnostico],
                    [svMaeDia_servicio_fky]
                )
                select 
                    clave, 
                    nombre, 
                    apellido 
                FROM nombres WHERE clave = @claves
            END
                
            
            SELECT [clave] FROM [dbo].[nombres]
            WHERE [clave] = @claves
            FETCH NEXT FROM lectorClaves INTO @claves

        END
    CLOSE lectorClaves
DEALLOCATE lectorClaves
```

En la tabla origen tengo 799 registros y en la de destino solo se insertan 789 lo que quiere decir que la condición no se está ejecutando correctamente y no está actualizando los campos únicos que están repetidos. ¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo funcionar?

Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el cursor en la fila

```
  ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE nombres
            SET clave = dbo.NuevaClase() 
            WHERE clave = @claves
 --- Acabas de cambiar el valor de la clave, por tanto la insert no es la misma
            INSERT INTO diagnosticos (
                [svMaeDia_pky],
                [svMaeDia_diagnostico],
                [svMaeDia_servicio_fky]
            )
            select 
                clave, 
                nombre, 
                apellido 
            FROM nombres WHERE 
   -- ahora clave puede contener otro valor.
    clave = @claves --
```

Una recomendación. **Evita los cursores**

Segunda opción, dado que `dbo.NuevaClase()` es una función escalar, puedes utilizar la sentencia `Merge` y en una sola instrucción y sin cursores, podrías insertar o actualizar esa tabla, en función de lo que leas de la otra.

[Merge](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/04/merge-upsert-insertar-o-actualizar-en-una-sola-sentencia/)

Si quieres iniciar ese camino, mejora el escenario de la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Lo he podido solucionar y te hare caso, evitaré los cursores porque en este caso, al tratar con gran cantidad de datos, tarda mucho en finalizar